# @Injects after @Produces?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to learn DI through Dagger 2 and apply it to our product. The Application-level things annotated with `@Singleton` are straightforward enough (e.g. `SharedPreferences`). In thinking of our architecture, there are several dependencies that are asynchronous in nature which I've imagined scoped at a `@ForSession` scoping.

- Our authentication token/account info, acquired from the Android `AccountManager`. Could be synchronous in the case of an existing, valid session. Could be asynchronous if no existing session and the `AccountManager` has to show the complete the login flow.
- Once we have a valid session token and session information:

  - Provide an `Endpoint` to fulfil dependencies so that our networking layer knows where to find the API.
  - acquire our "user" information from a network API.
  - pull additional supporting information from a network API (or local cache).
  - pull localized back-end strings from a network API (or local cache).
  - Get a component going that relies on a bound `Service`. Provide that component asynchronously only when the bound `Service` binding is complete.

The presentation layer should be gated on the receipt of the collection of these items. Aside from some sort of "loading" display, there's not much it can do without any of the above.

It feels like these dependencies fit the use-case for `@ProducerModule` and `@Produces`. I feel like I could have `@Produces ListenableFuture<>` methods for each of these dependencies, with perhaps a `SettableFuture<>` as the implementation. Perform whatever work is required, call `set()` on that future, dependency is met.

Where I get antsy is with this quote from the [Producers guide](http://google.github.io/dagger/producers.html).

> As in the above example, producer modules can be used seamlessly with ordinary modules, subject to the restriction that provided types cannot depend on produced types.

For the "gate presentation on everything being available" I can envision a composite object that could get `@Inject` with the unwrapped `T` of the futures. But is that even legal?

This is the closest I've come but it's explicitly calling the constructor of the composite, not injecting it. Is there a way to do this cleaner?

```
@ProducerModule
public class SessionModule {
@Produces
@ForSession
static ListenableFuture<User> produceSignedInUser(SessionManager sessionManager) {
    return sessionManager.getSignedInUserFuture();
}

@Produces
@ForSession
static ListenableFuture<BoundService> produceBoundService(SessionManager sessionManager) {
    return sessionManager.getBoundServiceFuture();
}

@Produces
@ForSession
static CompositeSessionInfo produceComposite(User user, BoundService service) {
    return new CompositeSessionInfo(user, service);
}
}
```

Then the component:

```
@ForSession
@ProductionComponent(modules = SessionModule.class)
public interface SessionComponent {
    ListenableFuture<CompositeSessionInfo> getCompsiteSessionInfoFuture();
}
```

And somewhere I want to gate I can do something like:

```
SessionComponent component = Dagger_SessionComponent.builder()
    .executor(executor)
    .build();

Futures.addCallback(component.getCompsiteSessionInfoFuture(), 
   new FutureCallback<CompositeSessionInfo> {
       public void onSuccess(CompositeSessionInfo result) {
           releaseTheHounds(result);
       }
       public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
           reportError(t);
       }
});
```

Am I way off on my understanding of this part of it? And an aside: why are the `@Produces` methods declared `static`? Is this required? (EDIT: the `static` sure isn't required, but I'm unsure what the intent was other than to not have instance fields in the `Module`).

**EDIT:**

I decided to create a [proof of concept project](https://github.com/bjdupuis/DaggerProducerTest) to abstract out my ideas from my actual project. Everything works as I'd like *except* that I'm unable to `@Inject` any of my `@Produce`d items, either the end result "composite" data or intermediate results. If I expose a getter in the component, I can get them so that's what I've done.

My current plan is to have this `@Producer` based asynchronous stuff off in a separate injectable module, then have the resultant dependencies get fed into a `@Provides` style module that feeds elsewhere so that they can be `@Inject`ed.

**EDIT EDIT:**

Updated the proof of concept to have a common precursor dependency to more closely mimic my needs. Still can't @Inject. I believe this about as good as I'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since it appears I'm going it alone I'll post my final conclusions as my own answer to hopefully help out someone else looking to do something similar.

I updated my [proof of concept project](https://github.com/bjdupuis/DaggerProducerTest) one more time. Now, once all of the asynchronous dependencies are met the new single composite dependency *is an actual @Module*, `@Produced` by the newly renamed `SessionProductionComponent`, then that module is registered as a component called the `SessionProvisionComponent`. This component is a standard `@Component` with `@Provide` methods to provide dependencies through the standard `@Inject` mechanism.

```
@Produces
@ForSession
public SessionProvisionModule produceSessionProvisionModule(Application app, SomeAsyncDependency someAsyncDependency, AnotherAsyncDependency anotherAsyncDependency) {
    SessionProvisionModule module = new SessionProvisionModule(someAsyncDependency, anotherAsyncDependency);
    ((App) app).createSessionProvisionComponent(module);
    return module;
}
```

Now in the `MainActivity`, when I need to acquire the session information it looks like so:

```
    App app = (App) getApplication();
    sessionProductionComponent = app.getSessionProductionComponent();
    if (app.getSessionProductionComponent() == null) {
        sessionProductionComponent = app.createSessionProductionComponent(new SessionProductionModule());
    }

    Futures.addCallback(sessionProductionComponent.getSessionProvisionModuleFuture(),
            new FutureCallback<SessionProvisionModule>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SessionProvisionModule result) {
                    app.getSessionProvisionComponent().inject(MainActivity.this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    // handle failure
                }
            });
```

Once the `Future` succeeds I can `inject()` the `MainActivity` and any annotated fields get `@Injected` with dependencies as one would expect. 
**In this way, I can actually have `@Inject` after `@Produce`.**

Not as clean as I'd like, but still better than without DI. Now any number of asynchronous dependencies, operating on whatever timeframe, can be satisfied in any order and once all of them are ready a single `Future` is set and a `SessionProvisionComponent` is made ready to inject dependencies with those `@Produced` dependencies.

Mostly happy.